# Socket : measure data transfer rate (in bytes / second) between 2 applications

Tags: c, performance, sockets

I have an application that keeps emitting data to a second application (consumer application) using TCP socket. How can I calculate the total time needed from when the data is sent by the first application until the data is received by the second application? Both the applications are coded using C/C++.
My current approach is as follow (in pseudocode):

```
struct packet{
   long sent_time;  
   char* data;  
}
```

**FIRST APP (EMITTER)  :**

```
packet p = new packet();
p.data = initialize data (either from file or hard coded)
p.sent_time = get current time (using gettimeofday function)

//send the packet struct (containing sent time and packet data)
send (sockfd, p, ...);
```

**SECOND APP (CONSUMER)**

```
packet p = new packet();
nbytes = recv (sockfd, p, .....); // get the packet struct (which contains the sent time and data)
receive_time = get current time
data transfer time = receive time - p.senttime (assume I have converted this to second)
data transfer rate = nbytes / data transfer time; // in bytes per second
```

However the problem with this is that the local clock time between the 2 applications (emitter and consumer) are not the same because they are both running on different computers, leading this result to a completely useless result.
Is there any other better way to do this in a proper way (programmatically), and to get as accurate data transfer rate as possible?

Comment: Without a synchronized time base, you're going to be in trouble.

Comment: Well the client and server apps are both running on different computers, so clock time will not be synchronized by any means.

Comment: "Both the applications are coded using C/C++" You should decide for one of both...

Comment: You could respect the local and code a Interface which is calculating the differences acording to the locals.

Answer (score 0):

If your protocol allows it, you could send back an acknowledgementn  from the server for the received packet. This is also a must if you want to be sure that the server received/processed the data.

If you have that, you can simply calculate the rate on the client. Just substract the RTT from the length of the send+ACK intervall and you'll have a quite accurate measurement.

Alternatively you can use a time syncronization tool like NTP to synchronize the clocks on the two servers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Even if your times were in sync, you would be calculating latency, not throughput. On every network connection chances are, that there is more than one packet en route at a given point in time, rendering your single-packet approach useless for throughput measurement.

E.g. Compare the ping time from your mobile to a HTTP server with the max download speed - ping time will be tens of ms, packet size will be ca. 1.5KByte, which would result in a much lower max throughput than observerd when downloading.

If you want to measure real throughput, use a blocking socket on the sender side and send e.g. 1 million packets as fast as the system will allow you, on the receiving side measure time between arrival of first packet and arrival of last packet.

If OTOH you want to accurately measure latency, use

```
struct packet{
   long sent_time;  
   long reflect_time;  
   char* data;  
}
```

and have the server reflect the packet. On the client side check all three timestamps, then reverse roles to get a grip on asymetric latencies.

Edit: I meant: The reflect time will be the "other" clock, so when running the test back and forth you will be able to filter out the offset.

Comment: What you're trying to do is more like determining the available bandwith. For that, there's `iperf`. You're biasing the results by sending lots of data. If the clients send short messages, then you want to see the bitrate for those short messages. Measure real-word scenarios, not theoretic limits. Note: by "packet" he meant that clock+data, not a single TCP packet.

Comment: That's what I wrote: The OP is measuring latency. There might be a reason for that (e.g. short messages that must be acknowledged), but there might also be not - in which case the transfer rate is the real thing: Both iperf and my approach do this.

Comment: And I am saying that he is in fact measuring throughput (per client). To use your HTTP example, if you have a server with lots of small files (eg: html, css, js, thumbnails), then doing test with a 100M movie would be cheating creating misleading results. but let's stop the arguing here, let's see how he responds ;)

Comment: Many small files on a HTTP server would be the textbook example for observed throughput being much higher than latency can explain: Parallel connections in the browser will make sure, there is more than one packet on the wire - this is why they are used, to use the whole possible throughput (or at least more of it) than what latency-bound single requests would allow.

Comment: Well (just to reflect his original scenario) how do you know his clients maintain multiple parallel connections or even able to do that? And for the HTTP server example: your clients typically just download a couple of small files (when traversing the site), so your measurement is still heavily biased.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion of terms. Yes in this case what I meant by "packet" is not a single TCP packet, but rather the data that I am sending/receiving, which is clock + the real data. I have an application that keeps emitting data to a consumer application which just consumes data from the first application, and I want to calculate the total time between when the data is emitted, until the data is received by the consumer application. So I guess this is a measurement of throughput right? Could you help me with simple pseudocode (logical flow) to measure this data transfer time and rate?

Comment: Do what the clients do in the real-world scenario. If on a single connection you send 100s of messages, then do that. If data to send is instantly available all the time then burst-send, if not, try to simulate the delays. Which part of the flow isn't clear? I think both he and I gave a good description of what to do.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck: I am not clear about the "reflect_time" that you mentioned. Could you elaborate more on how can I make use of this "reflect_time" to calculate the accurate time (time when data is received on computer B - time when data is sent on computer A)?